# Can I be a dual shield Paladin?

Tags: dnd-5e

I have an idea for a character but don’t know the specifics. A paladin with two shields, would I get the ac bonus from both shields, and would I be able to use the shields as weapons? If i can use them as weapons, how powerful would they be?

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: I do actually need to know how strong the shield is when used as a weapon though

Comment: There you go! Also, duplicates are okay, if you couldn't find those, maybe someone else will find yours! In the future, though, please try to limit one question per question, we work better with that.